# Swagger order inner http methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, swagger

quite new to this...
I'm trying to order a swagger.json nodeJS file by tags and inside by HTTP verbs.

In the example below I have a tag called Animals and under it three verbs: get, post, get because the first two are under the same path.

In my case, I want to see in Swagger preview as: get, get, post.

I tried to add an additional tag but it duplicated the code.
I also see there is some kind of sort method that may help but I only see it for ASP.net and not for Nodejs.

```json
"api/animals/elephant": {
  "get": {
    "tags": ["Animals"],
  },
  "post": {
    "tags": ["Animals"],
  }
}
"api/animals/dog": {
  "get": {
    "tags": ["Animals"],
  }
}
```

Comment: So you want to organize all `get` methods together and all `post` separately instead of organizing by endpoint?

Comment: yes, please. All get methods together and so on. but under same tag because I have more than one tag like "Animal"